# Return ranges of lines from text file PHP or LINUX

Tags: php, linux, file

I have a small issue here, I need to be able to read a file of unknown size it could be a a few hundred lines or many more the log files change all the time and depending on when i check. I would like to have a method that is in php or in linux that i can read a range of lines from a file. I dont want to have to read the entire file in to php memory then remove the lines because the file may be larger then the allowed memory of php.

I also want it to be using default php modules or default linux tools dont want to need to install anything because it needs to be portable.

Edit:

For the linux based options I would like to be able to supply more then one range, i may need to get a few different ranges of lines I know how to do it in php by not in linux and to avoid reading past lines i have already read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk 'NR>=10 && NR<=15' FILE
```

With awk (two ranges):

```
awk 'NR>=10 && NR<=15 || NR>=26 && NR<=28' FILE
```

With `ed`:

```
echo 2,5p | ed -s FILE
```

With `ed` and two ranges :

```
echo -e "2,5p\n7,8p" | ed -s FILE
```

Last but not least, a `sed` solution with two ranges (fastest solution, tested with `time`):

```
sed -n '2,5p;7,8p' FILE
```

Comment: Edited to add PHP solution too.

Comment: You PHP solution reads the whole file into memory. That was a specific problem to be avoided in the question.

Comment: will you explain how ed helps? i am a novice to some of the wounders of linux

Comment: It's another tool to display ranges. from wikipedia : _ed went on to influence ex, which in turn spawned vi. The non-interactive Unix command grep was inspired by a common special uses of qed and later ed, where the command g/re/p means globally search for the regular expression re and print the lines containing it. The Unix stream editor, sed implemented many of the scripting features of qed that were not supported by ed on Unix; sed, in turn, influenced the design of the programming language AWK, which in turn inspired aspects of Perl._ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ed_%28text_editor%29

Comment: still having a hard time seeing how i can supply it more then one range of numbers with out having to seek past lines i have already read?

Comment: Added example with 2 ranges ;)

Comment: this is really great stuyff thank you very much is there something you would recomend with the most speed

Answer (score 2):

What about something like

```
head -100 | tail -15
```

gives you lines 86-100

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat input.txt
q
w
e
r
t
y
u
i
$ sed -n 2,5p input.txt
w
e
r
t
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($lines_read < last_line_desired) {
  while ($line = fgets($filehandle, $buffersize) !== false)
    if (line >= first_desired_line) {
      push($interesting_lines, $line)
    }
  }
  $lines_read++
}
```

Opening the file handle, selecting the appropriately large enough buffer size to cover any expected line lengths, etc. is up to you.

If you're reading files that are regularly appended to, you should look into the [ftell](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftell.php) and [fseek](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) functions to note where you are in your data and skip past all the old stuff before reading more.

Comment: looks good but can you see the update that i posted may not apply to u as much but maybe you can give an example.